# Mod rewrite and $_GET variable

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a really simple mod-rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

As an example, it is transforming an url `www.mysite.com/a/b` to `www.mysite.com?url=a/b`

Issue here is that is does not allow to pass get parameters to my php.

Any clue on how to transform  `www.mysite.com/a/b?bar=42&foo=43` to `www.mysite.com?url=/a/b&bar=42&foo=43`

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule . index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

QSA = Query String Append

Comment: I used RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA], thanks a lot !